# Microsoft PowerBI - Check if one is also the other

Tags: powerbi

I'm working on a data science project for a platform between writers and readers.

The data is comprised of several csv files. The primary key is "account_ID". I'm currently trying to answer the question: "are writers also active readers?". I basically want to create a 2x2 matrix in which I can show how many accounts are just writers, just readers, none or both. I currently can't figure out how to check if they are both. Do you have any tips as to what function I could use to check and count how many ACCOUNT_IDs from the writers table also occur in the readers table?

Kind regards,

Thomas

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's much easier to answer with a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a relationship between the 2 tables on Account_ID, then the measure would be something like:

```
Writers who read = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( Writers ) , Readers )
```